# IPTables and Port Forwarding on an OpenVPNAS Server

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding, iptables-redirect

I have a new OpenVPNas server running on CentOS 7 (Not married to CentOS 7).  That I working on replacing an expensive Commercial VPN that has a Public Static IP.  Being that the OpenVPNas server is what amounts to my private VPN Server I just need to forward a couple of ports to a static internal VPN address to replace the Commercial Server.

I have the VPN Client setup and I can ping from the Server to the Client's static IP and from the Static IP to the server's Public IP and beyond.

I want the following ports on the server's IP forwarded/NAT'd/Masqueraded to the internal VPN.

```
Public TCP 80  ie Server Public's:80  -> 172.28.28.28:80
Public UDP Ports 2074-2093
Public TCP Ports 15425-15427
Public UDP Ports 5198-5200
Public TCP Ports 5198-5200
```

I have tried different `route` / `iptables` commands, but I have yet to figure out the magic bullet.  I believe it's a simple process but the solution is eluding me.  Via SSH the server can connect to the VPN port 80 and I get the client's via the VPN's web interface.  So the basic routing is working as expected.

I can't figure out the magic routing a packet destined for port 80 in the server's page to Forwarding

```
[root@vpn ~]# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 

[root@vpn ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         209.182.218.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
172.27.224.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 as0t0
172.27.228.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 as0t1
172.27.232.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 as0t2
172.27.236.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 as0t3
172.28.28.28    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 as0t0
209.182.218.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

[root@vpn ~]# ip route list
default via 209.182.218.1 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002 
172.27.224.0/22 dev as0t0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.224.1 
172.27.228.0/22 dev as0t1 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.228.1 
172.27.232.0/22 dev as0t2 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.232.1 
172.27.236.0/22 dev as0t3 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.236.1 
172.28.28.28 dev as0t0 proto static 
209.182.218.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 209.182.218.187 

[root@vpn ~]# ifconfig
as0t0: flags=4305  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  destination 172.27.224.1
        inet6 fe80::4da2:53e9:7fba:8f11  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 219  bytes 13438 (13.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 250  bytes 202093 (197.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t1: flags=4305  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.228.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  destination 172.27.228.1
        inet6 fe80::d557:1adc:c34c:4954  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 144 (144.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t2: flags=4305  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  destination 172.27.232.1
        inet6 fe80::be1a:bfd3:3c25:20f9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 144 (144.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t3: flags=4305  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.236.1  netmask 255.255.252.0  destination 172.27.236.1
        inet6 fe80::bfed:3f81:6938:bbc7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 144 (144.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 209.182.218.187  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 209.182.218.255
        inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fecc:ddf3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:16:3e:cc:dd:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11673  bytes 1350674 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 14  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5295  bytes 1099520 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9  bytes 748 (748.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 748 (748.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your OpenVPN-AS has a dynamic or static public IP assigned to interface **eth0**, we will use interface name when creating firewall rules. This way will make sure that the rule work in both situations. In this case, you need to configure [Destination NAT](https://ipwithease.com/snat-vs-dnat/)

If your VPN server has a tunnel interface **tun0** with an IP of **172.28.28.1** and the internal webserver with an IP of **172.28.28.28** listening on port **80**

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp   -d eth0   --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.28.28
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0  -p tcp -m tcp   -d 172.28.28.28  --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 172.28.28.1
```

Comment: And if I had a 2nd IP available and wanted to "bind" all ports on the 2nd Public to the Internal IP and have the source also show up as the 2nd public.